# Get the current user inside jira workflow validator

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, opensymphony

I want to create a workflow validator which will not allow the reporter of the issue to execute certain steps from the workflow. For that purpose somehow I have to get the User object or the user id of the user executing the action. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject the `JiraAuthenticationContext` And then call `jiraAuthenticationContext.getLoggedInUser();`

you can find the documentation about the JiraAuthenticationContext here:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/5.0.1/com/atlassian/jira/security/JiraAuthenticationContext.html

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, although I'll left it as is now with my solution :)

Comment: Thanks! :) I  recommend you stick with the atlassian API way, so there won't be any problems - e.g. in case of a minor upgrade of your jira instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've managed to do it:

```
private String getCurrentIssueProcessorId(Map<?, ?> transientVars, Map<?, ?> args){
        String processorId = (String) args.get(ARG_USER_NAME);
        if(null == processorId || processorId.isEmpty()){
            WorkflowContext workflowContext = (WorkflowContext) transientVars.get(ARG_CONTEXT);
            processorId = workflowContext.getCaller();
        }

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("Issue processor: " + processorId);
        }

        return processorId;
}
```

where `ARG_CONTEXT` is the string `context` and `ARG_USER_NAME` is the string `username`

Comment: Can't you just inject the `JiraAuthenticationContext` 
And then call

    jiraAuthenticationContext.getUser();

?

Comment: I guess I can. It's just I didn't know such class existed :)

Comment: PS: authContext.getUser() seems to be deprecated

Comment: you are developing on jira 7?

Comment: Developing with jira 5.0 API :) My eclipse marks this method as deprecated.

Comment: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/5.0.1/com/atlassian/jira/security/JiraAuthenticationContext.html you need to call getLoggedInUser() now but it should also be fine to call getUser() with Jira 5.0